# should we make different action for update and add operation of some entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions

Is it a good practice to use same Action for both add & Update operation.

for example i am working on a Project in which i havea table with fllowing fields

```
public class UserProfile
{
     public int Id{get;set;}
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public string Email{get;set;}
}
```

and i have a action which takes this model as arguement and do save and update

```
public class UserProfileController : Controller
{

  public ViewResult UserProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
  {
        if(userProfile.Id == -1)
        {
            _accessor.Add(userProfile);
        }
        else
        {
            _accessor.Update(userProfile);
        }
  }
}
```

the function is working properly but i want to know that if it is a good practice or should i make different actions for insert and update operations.

and if its a good practice to have one action for both the operations then what should be the name of the action.

Comment: I don't see any problem as long as you can efficiently handle your business logic.But why to make it complicated ?

Comment: I would say this comes down to which conventions you are using throughout your application/solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate. And why:

1. It would make the user code more clear: You will easily find
   where user intended to use the add option of this function and where
   he intended to use the add property.
2. Interface change becomes problematic: If you have implementation with one function and you decide     one day to add argument that relevant only for the update part of it.
   Next you will refactor your client code passing this arguments. What
   would you pass in all places that you intended to add? some null? It
   would be ugly...
3. Testing/bug risk: If you have implementation with one function and, you decide to make some changes to your "update" part, you always have a risk that you made some bug also in the "add" part. Separating to two functions will eliminate this risk. Of course, your case is simple, but I am talking more generally.